# Unable to deduce that how $K^n\approx M_a\{\langle x_1 -a_1,\dots, x_n -a_n\rangle\mid a\in K^n\}$

Tags: algebraic-geometry

I am reading notes on Introduction to algebraic geometry  which I got from a senior and I am unable to think how should I deduce this result.

Author proves  that $K^n \approx \operatorname{Hom}_{K-alg} (K[x_1,\dots,x_n],K)$ by using the following map $(a_1,...,a_n) \to \epsilon_a : K[x_1,\dots,x_n]\to K$, where the map $\epsilon_a : x_i \to a_i$. Then author proves that $\epsilon_a $ is surjective and that $\ker(\epsilon_a)=\langle x_1- a_1,\dots,x_n-a_n\rangle$ and $\langle x_1-a_1,\dots,x_n-a_n\rangle$ is a maximal ideal because $K^n$ is a field so the kernel of the map must be a maximal ideal. (I understand all till now.)

But, I don't know how author wrote the next statement: So, we have proved that $K^n \approx \{M_a= \langle x_1- a_1,\dots,x_n-a_n\rangle\mid a\in K^n\}$.

I don't know how to deduce that with what was just proved and I need help.

Comment: is $K^n$ really a field ?

Comment: I've made some upgrades to your mathjax. Please take a look and keep these in mind for the future.

Comment: @KReiser Ok thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The author has defined a map $K^n\to {\rm Specm}(K[x_1,\cdots,x_n])$ - the set of maximal ideals in $K[x_1,\cdots,x_n]$.

You need to show that this map is injective, so you can conclude $K^n$ is in one to one correspondence with the set of maximal ideals obtained this way: $\{M_a|\,\, a\in K^n\}$.

If $a\neq a'$ then for some $i$ we have $a_i\neq a'_i$.  Thus $x_i-a_i\in M_a$ but $x_i-a'_i\in M_{a'}$.

Thus if $M_a=M_{a'}$ then we have $0\neq a_i-a'_i\in M_a$.   However $\epsilon_a(a_i-a'_i)=a_i-a'_i\neq 0$ so $a_i-a'_i\notin M_a$.

We conclude $a\neq a'$ implies $M_a\neq M_{a'}$.

Comment: How did you deduced that $x_i -a_i \in M_a$?

Comment: It is in the definition of $M_a$ that you wrote down in the question.

Comment: Why can't we have $a_i =a_{i'}\in M_a$ in the next line?

Comment: If two vectors are not equal, then they must differ in some component.

Comment: Thank you very much!

Comment: Mate, I am really sorry that I ask you this way but few of questions of mine are not answered by anyone and I don't have any other help, so I ask you this way.Can you also help me with this question, I am badly struck on it:https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4323645/how-to-prove-this-set-to-be-closed-under-properties-of-a-field

Answer (score 0):

You undestand that $\epsilon$ is surjective. So you're left to show that it is one-to-one.

The most naïve approach would be to start from $a \in K^n$ such that $\epsilon_a = 0$.

This is equivalent to $\ker (\epsilon_a) = K[x_1, \cdots , x_n]$.

Comment: @InfinteLooper How is this equivalent to $ker(\epsilon_a)= K[x_1,...,x_n]$? Can you please tell?

Comment: Which implication is struggling you ?

Comment: How is $\epsilon_a =0$ equivalent to $ ker(\epsilon_a) = K[x_1,...,x_n]$?

Comment: Can you please reply?

Comment: An equivalence is two implications, which one is struggling you ?

Comment: I am sorry but both.

Comment: Because $\epsilon_a = 0$ if and only if $\forall x \in K[x_1, \cdots, x_n], \epsilon_a(x) = 0$.

Comment: Maybe it's better statted this way : let $f : E \to F$ be linear. We have $f = 0$ iif $\ker (f) = E$ (iif $\forall x \in E, f(x) = 0$)

Comment: There is no $a\in K^n$ with $\epsilon_a=0$.  In fact $\epsilon_a(1)=1$ for any $a\in K^n$.  The question does not mention any map $\epsilon$ or ask to show that it is one to one.  For $n>0$ the $\epsilon_a$ are not one to one - their kernels are maximal ideals, which are non-zero.  I think you have misunderstood the question here.

Comment: Damn, I was stuck in the fact that it was an isomorphism of Vector spaces, but indeed it is not, sorry haha, thanks for pointing out the mistake.