# Module localization, Natural map, hom and bijectivity

Tags: abstract-algebra, commutative-algebra, localization

The following question is from my assignment on localization of modules and I need help with it.

> Let V be an A-module, $S\subseteq A$ be a multiplicatively closed subset and let ${t_S}^V: V \to S^{-1} V, x\to x/1$ be a natural map.

(a) Prove that $\ker {t_S}^V=\{ x\in V | sx =0$ for some $s\in S\}$.

Unfortunately, I am not able to prove this and I think $\ker{t_S}^V$ should be all x in V such that x/1=0 ie x=0 because the map is $x\to x/1$. I don't understand why s should be there with x.

(b) The map ${t_S}^V$ is bijective iff all ${\lambda}_s $, $s\in S$ is bijective, where $\lambda_s : V \to V $  is the map $ v \to sv$.

Again the map : $x \to x/1$ is injective and surjective always.I am unable to correlate it with multiplication by s.

(c) The natural ring hom $t_S : A\to S^{-1}A$  is bijective iff $S\subseteq A^{\times}$.

Due to the problem in understanding the map, I am not able to attempt (c) also.

Please guide.

Comment: What is the definition of $S^{-1}V$? How is $x/1$ defined?

Comment: @Mindlack x/1 means that x belongs to V and 1 belongs to S, $S^{-1} V$  has elements of the form $s^{-1}v$ where $s\in S$ and $v\in V$.

Comment: And what are the operation rules on $S^{-1}V$? When are $x/s$ and $y/t$ equal?

Comment: @Mindlack x/s and y/t are equal when we have xt = ys. How exactly will it help?

Comment: That isn’t the correct definition. And you can’t solve the problem if you don’t have the right definition.

Comment: @Mindlack What is the right definition ? Can you please tell?

Comment: $x/s=y/t$ (for $x,y \in V,s,t \in S$) iff there exists some $u \in S$ such that $u(tx-sy)=0$.

Comment: @Mindlack Ya , my bad.

Comment: @Mindlack Thanks , I have proved (a) and equivalence of injectivity in (b), but can you please help with equivalence of surjectivity in (b) and (c)?

Comment: Note that (b) implies (c). For (b), if $t_S^V$ is bijective, what is the inverse image of some $v/s$, $v \in V$, $s \in S$?

Comment: Two elements $a/s,b/s'\in S^{-1}A$ define the same element iff there exists some $s''\in S$ s.t. $s''(as'-bs)=0$. Hence it follows that $x/1=0/1$ iff there exists some $s\in S: s(x\cdot 1-0\cdot 1)=sx=0$. Which immediately shows the claim for $\ker$.

Comment: @nilsw I have shown injectivity in (b). I am asking for surjectivity.

Answer (score 1):

For part (a): $x\in$ker$({t_S}^V)$ if and only if ${t_S}^V x=\frac x1=\frac 01$.  This is equivalent to there existing $s\in S$ such that $$sx=s(x\cdot1-0\cdot 1)=0.$$

---

If $\lambda_s$ is surjective for all $s\in S$, then given $s\in S$ and $v\in V$ we may find $x\in V$ with $sx=v$, so $t^V_S(x)=\frac x1=\frac vs$.  Thus $t^V_S$ is surjective.

You have already shown that if $\lambda_s$ is injective for all $s\in S$, then $t^V_S$ is injective.

Thus if $\lambda_s$ is bijective for all $s\in S$ then $t^V_S$ is bijective.

Conversely suppose $t_S^V$ is bijective. You have already shown that $\lambda_t$ is injective for all $t\in S$.

Given $v\in V$ and $s\in S$ we want to find $x\in V$ with $sx=v$, so we can deduce that $\lambda_s$ is surjective.

As we are given $t_S^V$ is surjective, we know there exists $x\in V$ such that $\frac x1=\frac vs$.  That is: $t(sx-v)=0$ for some $x\in V$ and $t\in S$.

As $\lambda_t$ is injective, we know $sx=v$.  Thus $\lambda_s$ is surjective, as required.

---

Part c is just the special case where $V=A$.  We know $t_S=T^A_S$ is bijective if and only if $\lambda_s$ is bijective for every $s\in S$.

If $\lambda_s$ is bijective then in particular $\lambda_s(y)=1$ for some $y\in A$.  Thus $sy=1$ and $s\in A^\times$.

Conversely, if $st=1$, then $\lambda_s\lambda_t=\lambda_t\lambda_s=1$, so $\lambda_s$ is bijective (it has a two-sided inverse $\lambda_t$).

So the $s$ for which $\lambda_s$ is bijective are precisely the elements of $A^\times$.

Thus $\lambda_s$ is bijective for every $s\in S$ precisely when $S\subseteq A^\times$.

Comment: why is s never equal to 0 in (b)? as you wrote that sx=v implies x= v/s so you must show that $s\neq 0$.

Comment: How does st=1 in (c) implies that $\lambda_s\lambda_t=\lambda_t\lambda_s=1$ ?

Comment: Can you also have a look on this:https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4335069/localization-saturation-and-nilradical-help-needed-and-proof-verification

Comment: The statement $\frac x1=\frac vs$ means there exists $t\in S$ such that $t(sx-1 v)=0$.  If $sx=v$ then we can just take $t=1$: $$1(sx-  1 v)=0.$$ Thus by definition $\frac x1=\frac vs$.  $${}$$ So when it comes to dividing, the important thing to check is that what you are dividing by is in $S$.  This means that you are allowed to divide by $0$ if $0\in S$.  However in this case, $0(ax-by)=0$ implies that $\frac xb =\frac ya$ for any $x,y\in V$ and $a,b\in S$, so $S^{-1}V=\{0\}$.

Comment: If $st=1$ then $$\lambda_s\lambda_t=\lambda_{st}=\lambda_1=1_V.$$  In words: multiplying by $t$ and then multiplying by $s$  is the same as multiplying by $st$.

Comment: I am sorry , I am asking this after a lot of months but I think you didn't gave any outline for (a).

Comment: I have added an answer to (a).