# Maximal ideals in finitely generated algebras over a field

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, commutative-algebra, modules, tensor-products

Let $k$ be an algebraically closed field, let $A$ be a finitely generated $k$-algebra. If $m\subset A$ is a maximal ideal, show that it is generated by $\operatorname{dim}_k m/m^2$ elements.

Consider the localization $A_m$; the proposition 2.8 (Atiyah-MacDonald) states that $mA_m$ is generated (as ideal) by $\operatorname{dim}_{A_m/mA_m}(m/m^2)A_m$ elements.

In general $A_m/mA_m\cong A/m$, but here $A/m\cong k$ by Zariski's lemma. So $mA_m$ is generated by $\operatorname{dim}_k(m/m^2)A_m$ elements.

Now, as $k$-modules $(m/m^2)A_m$ and $m/m^2$ are isomorphic; in fact we can view $m/m^2$ (and $k$)  as an $A$-module, and recover the $k$-module structure as $k\otimes _A m/m^2$. Similarly, we can view $(m/m^2)A_m$ (and $k$) as an $A_m$-module, and recover the $k$-module structure as $k\otimes_{A_m}(m/m^2)A_m$. But also, we get the $A_m$-module structure of $(m/m^2)A_m$ as $A_m\otimes_Am/m^2$. Since $k\otimes_{A_m} A_m\cong k$, $$k\otimes _A m/m^2\cong k\otimes_{A_m} A_m\otimes_Am/m^2.$$

Thus $\operatorname{dim}_km/m^2=\operatorname{dim}_k(m/m^2)A_m$, and we are left to show that, if $n\in \mathbb N$ elements generate $mA_m$ as ideal, also $m$ is generated by $n$ elements in $A$. However this I don't understand if is true, i.e. from $n$ elements generating $(m/m^2)A_m$ I don't see how to get $n$ elements generating $m/m^2$. Thanks for any suggestion.

Comment: What do you mean when you write $(m/m^2)A_m$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $k=\mathbb{C}$, $A=\mathbb{C}\times \mathbb{C}$ and $m=\langle (1,0)\rangle$.

Then $m/m^2=\{0\}$ but $m\neq 0$.

Comment: For helping the OP a little more, we may write $A=\mathbb C[x]/(x^2-x)$ and $\mathfrak m=(x)$.

Comment: Sorry I was so convinced of this result that I didn't see the many counterexamples. Just looking at Nakayama's lemma, one should see that if $A$ is a ring and $I\subset A$ an ideal not in the Jacobson radical, $I/I^2$ can be zero without $I$ being zero (in the ring that you both proposed the Jacobson radical should be $(0)$ for instance).

Comment: Just a last question: if at least what I proved is true, i.e. that $\operatorname{dim}_km/m^2=\operatorname{dim}_k(m/m^2)A_m$, can I say that $\operatorname{dim}A\ge\operatorname{dim}_km/m^2$? I'd say yes because $\operatorname{dim}A\ge\operatorname{dim}A_m=\operatorname{dim}_km/m^2$. Thanks

Comment: By dim $A$ do you mean the Krull dimension?

Comment: @tkf yes I mean Krull dimension

Comment: It looks plausible but I do not know enough about the theory here to confirm your reasoning.  Sorry.  I definitely agree that dim $A\geq$ dim $A_m$ with equality attained for some $m$.

Comment: If it helps, you can deduce a proof that dim $A=$sup${}_{m\,\,{\rm maximal}}\{$ dim$A_m\}$ from part (b) of this question I answered yesterday: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4335069/localization-saturation-and-nilradical-help-needed-and-proof-verification/4360683#4360683

Comment: Thank you, but I know that fact; I am insecure about the isomorphism of $m/m^2$ and $(m/m^2)A_m$ as $k$-modules.

Comment: Given $\frac ax\in mA_m$, we have $y\in A$ such that $xy=1+z$ with $z\in m$.  Then $\frac ax=\frac{ay}{1+z}=\frac{ay}1-\frac{ayz}{1+z}$, with $\frac{ayz}{1+z}\in m^2A_m$.  Thus the natural map $m/m^2\to (m/m^2)A_m$ is surjective.

Comment: For injectivity, note that for $a\in m$, we have $a\mapsto 0$ only if $ax\in m^2$ for some $x\notin m$.  Then $xy=1+z$ with $z\in m$ so $a(1+z)\in m^2$.  As $az\in m^2$ we may deduce $a\in m^2$.

Comment: When $A$ is a local ring one can have $\dim A<\dim_km/m^2$.

Comment: @tkf The local ring of any singular point of a variety works. $k[x,y]_{(x,y)}/(xy)$, for one.